# looking for a word for "in the middle/close to the middle of a scale/spectrum"

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word of something that is in the middle of a scale, like something that is little or inclined to either of the extremes of a spectrum, because I was just taking an mbti test (the 16 personality types) and I got 52-48 in the thinking-feeling scale, so what should I fill in the blank?:"my result in the thinking-feeling scale was _____.", I know it's not exactly in the middle but it's very close to.

Comment: Depends on the nature of the scale. But _middle_ or _median_ are standard, _Middle_ refers to a linear scale, horizontal or vertical; _median_ has a specific statistical meaning.

Comment: A balanced score in a Myers-Briggs scale is unusual.